# IV or latent factor to process multiple measures?

Tags: factor-analysis, measurement-error, instrumental-variables

I have several measures on different memory tests. I consider these measures may actually measure different aspects of memory functioning and every measure contains a measurement error. 
I am thinking about two strategies. First one is using one measure as instrument variable. If errors are assumed independent, then IV gives a noise free measure. The second option is using factor analysis. I will derive the first factor and use it as an error-free measure.

Are these two methods valid? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is somewhat unclear to me, but I believe that **factor analysis** is the way to go. In case, if there is no substantial prior *theoretical knowledge* (that is, your research is *exploratory* in nature), I would perform [exploratory factor analysis (EFA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploratory_factor_analysis) first. That would give your ideas about what *constructs* exactly are measured by your *indicators* (some might overlap or even measure the same thing). Then, if desired, you could perform a [confirmatory factor analysis (CFA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmatory_factor_analysis), which would validate your EFA results and hypothesized *measurement model*.